Triple Integral Problem $\iiint\limits_Q f(x,y,z) \,\mathrm dV$
Earlier, I saw the unanswered problem for triple integral and I want to try to solve the problem. The problem is like this:

Evaluate $\displaystyle\iiint\limits_Q \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}\,\mathrm dV$ using the spherical coordinates where $Q$ is given by $-1\leq x\le1$, $-\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y\leq\sqrt{1-x^2}$, and $0\leq z \leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$.

Here's my solution to how I work on this problem:
As the problem said I have to use the spherical coordinates, I use these equations to convert everything into spherical coordinates.
$$x=\rho\sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta)\quad y=\rho\sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta)\quad z=\rho \cos(\varphi) $$
Therefore,
\begin{aligned} f(x,y,z)=\left( x^2+y^2+z^2 \right)^{3/2}\implies f\left(\rho,\theta,\varphi \right)&=\left( \rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\cos^2(\theta)+\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\sin^2(\theta)+\rho^2\cos^2(\varphi) \right)^{3/2}\\&= \left( \rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\left( \cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta) \right)+\rho^2\cos^2(\varphi) \right)^{3/2}\\&=\left( \rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)+\rho^2\cos^2(\varphi) \right)^{3/2}\\&=\left( \rho^2\left( \sin^2(\varphi)+\cos^2(\varphi) \right) \right)^{3/2}\\&=\left( \rho^2 \right)^{3/2}\\&=\rho^3 \end{aligned}
Next up, I do the same for the interval $x$, $y$, and $z$. These are my way of how do I transform into the spherical coordinates.
\begin{aligned} z=0\implies \rho\cos(\varphi)&=0 \\ {\rho=0}\quad\cos(\varphi)&=0\implies\begin{cases} \varphi&=\dfrac\pi2\\\varphi&=\dfrac{3\pi}2 \end{cases} \end{aligned}
These ones I use $\frac\pi2\leq\varphi\leq \frac{3\pi}2$. Then the left one
\begin{aligned} z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\implies\rho\cos(\varphi)&=\sqrt{1-\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\cos^2(\theta)-\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\sin^2(\theta)}\\\rho\cos(\varphi)&=\sqrt{1-\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\left( \cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta) \right)}\\\rho\cos(\varphi)&=\sqrt{1-\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)}\\\rho^2\cos^2(\varphi)&=1-\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\\\rho^2\cos^2(\varphi)+\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)&=1\\\rho^2\left( \cos^2(\varphi)+\sin^2(\varphi) \right)&=1\\\rho^2&=1\\\rho&=\pm\sqrt1\\\rho&=\pm1 \end{aligned}
which means $-1\leq \rho\leq 1$. Now,
\begin{aligned} y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}\implies\rho\sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta)&=-\sqrt{1-\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\cos^2(\theta)}\\\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\sin^2(\theta)&=1-\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\cos^2(\theta)\\ \rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\cos^2(\theta)+\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\sin^2(\theta)&=1\\ \rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)\left( \cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta) \right)&=1\\\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)&=1\\\rho^2&=\frac1{\sin^2(\varphi)}\\\rho^2&=\csc^2(\varphi)\\\rho&=\pm\sqrt{\csc^2(\varphi)}\\\rho&=\pm\csc(\varphi) \end{aligned}
which means I don't know if this is correct. Because I don't think this has two $\rho$'s for the integral then I don't know if this is correct. Can you tell me what's wrong with this?

The constrain on $\rho$ is $\rho>0$, so it can't be negative. And $\phi\in[0,\pi]$

You are misinterpreting the bounds. The integral is over a solid hemisphere.

Your calculations are correct, however I think you errors might be the choice to derived bounds for $\rho$. Note that $0\leq z\leq\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ is a sphere, $-\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y\leq\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so when you extend to $\mathbb{R}^3$, you get a cylinder.
Hence you get different bounds for $\rho$ if you choose the two above bounds.

Hint: However there is another easy way to change variables. It is not hard to see that the bound is a northern-hemisphere, so bounds in spherical coordinates can be derived easily. (Think of it geometrically)

Try to plot it first and find the bound (each variables are independent from each other), and it should be easy to find $dV$ in terms of $d\rho d\phi d\theta$.

I mean will the triple integral comes out $\displaystyle\iiint\limits_Q f(x,y,z) ,\mathrm dV=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^\pi\int\limits_{0}^{1}\rho^5\sin(\varphi),\mathrm d\rho,\mathrm d\varphi,\mathrm d\theta$?

Bound for $\phi$ is wrong, notice the reigon is north hemisphere
